# many divs with same class - different background

Tags: random, background

so i have many divs with same class on the same page. i would like to add different backgrounds for each of them on my own choise(having 5-6 random backgrounds)

i found this code on the internet. but it chooses the same random color for all the divs.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

/***********************************************
* Random Content Colors script- © Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (www.dynamicdrive.com)
* This notice MUST stay intact for legal use
* Visit Dynamic Drive at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for full source code
***********************************************/

//specify list of random background colors to apply to CSS class "randomcolor"
//For each entry, you can optionally specify a text and link color via the syntax:
// "BackgroundColor:TextColor" OR "BackgroundColor:TextColor:LinkColor"
var randombgcolors=["green:white:yellow", "#DDF4FF", "#FFFF97", "#CFFF9F"]

var rbcssrule=""
var randomnum=Math.floor(Math.random()*randombgcolors.length)
if (randombgcolors[randomnum].indexOf(":")!=-1){
rbcssrule="background-color: "+randombgcolors[randomnum].split(":")[0]+";"
rbcssrule+="color: "+randombgcolors[randomnum].split(":")[1]+";"
}
else
rbcssrule="background-color: "+randombgcolors[randomnum]+";"

document.write('<style type="text/css">\n')
document.write('.randomcolor{'+rbcssrule+'}\n')
if (randombgcolors[randomnum].split(":").length==3) //if link color specified
document.write('.randomcolor a{color:'+randombgcolors[randomnum].split(":")[2]+';}\n')
document.write('<\/style>')

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like that code is setting its randomly chosen color to just one class: randomcolor. Assuming that all of your divs have that same class, they will all get that random color.

EDIT:

Check this JSFiddle I made, it should get you what you are looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/VXG36/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="random">Div 1</div>
<div class="random">Div 2</div>
<div class="random">Div 3</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var randomColors = ["green","yellow","red","blue","orange","pink","cyan"];
    $(".random").each(function(index) {
        var len = randomColors.length;
        var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*len);
        $(this).css("backgroundColor",randomColors[randomNum]);
        //Removes color from array so it can't be used again
        randomColors.splice(randomNum, 1);
    });
});
```

Comment: do you guys have any other codes to use different colors with same class? its because i use joomla and my articles has same classes and thats impossible to change.

Comment: Hello Chad. its exactly what im looking for. Thank you very much. but i got a problem to insert it to my code. can you pleas help me?

i dont know where to put the javascript code?
at the bottom of my index.php i have put the javascript code between a  <script> </script> tag, but it doesnt seem to show up?

edit: nevermind. it works fine now. thank you very much!! can i give you some thumps up or rep? and how?

Comment: No problem, I'm glad to hear it's working! Selecting it as the answer and voting it up is what gives rep for future reference.

Comment: Btw. is it possible to do something with the script, so the colors only appear maximum one time?

Comment: Just updated my answer again to do that, as well as the JSFiddle. Using `.splice()` will remove a color from the array after it is used. Note that this will no longer be in the array until the page is refreshed/revisited.

Comment: thanks. that works like a charm. amazing.. just what i looked for. thank you very much Chad!

Comment: Sorry to bother you. but i have another question. is it possible to use this code doing same thing but only for the font color and not background? if so how? i have the idea to switch the backgroundColor to something else? i tried with "color" but didnt work.

Comment: Hello Chad. sorry to bother you again, but I ran into a problem, or maybe a modification of the script. I changed the "backgroundColor to Color and use it for my links. but the script blocks for my a:hover tag, so i cant use a hover tag, what do i have to get my a:hover tag to work again?

Comment: You can use `.hover('on hover function', 'off hover function')` to do this. Check out this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VXG36/3/

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that your *randomnum* will always be 4.  When it hits your "green:white:yellow" collection it will always split into randombgcolors[randomnum].split(":")[0] which is green, and randombgcolors[randomnum].split(":")[1] which is always white. Maybe when you hit *randomnum* as one you need a nother randomizer to pick between 0 and 2 to get your random green:white:yellow color.

Comment: do you guys have any other codes to use different colors with same class? its because i use joomla and my articles has same classes and thats impossible to change.