# Use Javascript to assign random background color to images on page load

Tags: image, random, colors, background

I'm not good with javascript but think this is doable and could use your help.

I have a div class called .thumbs, and inside this div are all the thumbnails for a lightbox gallery (and these thumbnails are also links).

The images have padding and border, so you can see the image's background color in the padding.

I want a script that will assign a random color out of five as the background image for each of these images on :hover.

I think it would be best if these colors were assigned only once on pageload, instead of it being assigned a new random color every time an image is hovered over.

I took a look at this answer by Chad, for assigning random colors to a div class, but I couldn't get it to work even as it was intended, although the jsfiddle looks great. I'm sure there was something weird going on on my end.. [many divs with same class - different background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259396/many-divs-with-same-class-different-background)

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Did you use JQuery to reproduce what's in the jsfiddle?

Comment: Um.. I thought I had but in review I had not. So the script I linked to works great and I will try to adjust it to my needs and come back to this thread if I need help with that. Embarrassed! Thank you!

Comment: So the script is working fine for randomly assigning colors to divs with ".random" class. 

Now, how do I assign it to the background color of the images?
The CSS I'm currently using to assign one color to them is
.thumbs a img:hover{background-color:#CC99FF;}

I've played with it a bit and my original idea about how to do it failed.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you could do it like so (this code also requires jquery):

```
<style>
    .color-1 a img:hover{background-color:red;}
    .color-2 a img:hover{background-color:blue;}
    .color-3 a img:hover{background-color:green;}
    .color-4 a img:hover{background-color:yellow;}
    .color-5 a img:hover{background-color:orange;}
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){ // this is a shortcut for "on document ready"
        // For each element with the class thumb we find:
        $('.thumb').each(function(){
            // add random class to assign the color
            $(this).addClass('color-' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1));
        });
    })
</script>
...
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: That is an interesting approach to it and I wouldn't have thought of that, I will definitely try it out. Thanks!

For the sake of understanding the concept, is there another approach to this?

I got the code in my OP to apply to the background color of links, so applying to bg of an img should be equally straightforward.

What did not work for me was when I added :hover to it, in the same way as css. It just broke and didn't change anything. So, is there a special format to enter the :hover part, or does that need to be declared in the actual JS as a mouseover event or something like that?

Comment: I'd also really like to add on to it so that the hover color  remains after the image is clicked/"active", until another image is clicked.