# Javascript: Assign random background color to image on hover

Tags: random, colors, background, hover

I'm not good with javascript but think this is doable and could use your help.

I have a div class called .thumbs, and inside this div are all the thumbnails for a lightbox gallery (and these thumbnails are also links).

The images have padding and border, so you can see the image's background color in the padding.

I want a script that will assign a random color out of five as the background color for each of these images on :hover.

I think it would be best if these colors were assigned only once on pageload, instead of it being assigned a new random color every time an image is hovered over.

I tried adjusting the script I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18259491/2860129

I changed it from .random to .thumbs img, and the script assigned the color to the background of the image as expected. However adding any kind of :hover to it breaks it and nothing happens. Is there a certain place I need to add the :hover, or does the hover action need to be defined in the javascript with onmouseover or something like that..?

Additionally, I'd like for the background color to stay, once the image is clicked, until another image is clicked/selected. And if anyone can add to this code so that there will never be two of the same color in a row, that would be great. (I deleted the "Removes color from array so it can't be used again" section).

Thanks to anyone who can help, I imagine these are pretty simple problems but I appreciate it a  lot.

Answer (score 0):

With jquery

```
$(".thumbs").hover(function() {
 color = new Array(1,1,1).map(function(val) { return ~~(Math.random()*255); }).join(",")
 return "rgb(" + color + ");";
});
```

Comment: I cannot get this to work at all. I checked to make sure that jquery is loaded, and it is. I even removed your code and tried this simple little script instead, and even with that there is nothing happening (http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_hover) What could be the problem??

Comment: What's not happening? The color changes on hover, then changes to pink as you specified.

Comment: I mean when I add that paragraph hover script to my page and test it, it does not work and the paragraph color doesn't change on hover. I thought this was relevant because if that unrelated script won't work on my page either, that might indicate the problem/reason why the script that I actually want to use won't work.